# Laravel store single form values in 2 different tables

Tags: laravel

Hi guys i am trying to store my single form values in a 2 different tables. so far i have created 2 different tables with different columns..

here is my controller function where i have added my 2 models with column values:

```
 public function store(Request $request, topic $topic)
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'subject_type' => 'required',
        'grades' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
    ];

    $topic_id = $request->input('topic');
    if ($topic_id != '0') {
        $rules['topic'] = 'required|exists:topics,id';
    } else {
        $topic_id = null;
    }

    $request->validate($rules);

    $topicModel = new Topic();
    $topicModel->name = $request->input('name');
    $topicModel->description = $request->input('description');
    $topicModel->sort_order = $topicModel->getNextSortNumber();
    $topicModel->subject_id = $request->input('subject');
    $topicModel->parent_id = $topic_id;
    $topicModel->grades = $request->input('grades');
    $topicModel->status = $request->input('status');
    $topicModel->created_by = auth()->user()->id;

    $topicModel->save();

    $topicLookupMasterModel = new topic_lookup_master();
    
    $topicLookupMasterModel->tlm_topic_id = $topicModel->id;
    $topicLookupMasterModel->tlm_sub_topic_id = $topicModel->subject_id;
    $topicLookupMasterModel->{'tlm'.$topicModel->grades}  = $topicModel->grades; //here i have multiple grades.if i have grades 3,5 i want to store those values in my columns tlm_3 and tlm_5.

    $topicLookupMasterModel->save();

    return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('status-success', 'Topic created successfully');
}
```

So far i am getting error as `Array to string conversion`

And i am trying to store my grades also in particular columns depend on gradeid..i have columns like tlm_1 to tlm_15 for storing grades value..

for example if i have grades selected as 3,5 it should store in columns tlm_3 and tlm_5 columns..

Can anyone help me  how can i approach this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't like the way you approach the problem and the database design. But to answer to your problem. Here I come the short solution:

```php
$gradeColumnName = "tlm_{$topicModel->grades}" // this should be "tlm_3" or "tlm_5" or sth like that
```

now the line `$topicLookupMasterModel->{'tlm'.$topicModel->grades}  = $topicModel->grades;` change to

```php
$topicLookupMasterModel->$gradeColumnName = $topicModel->grades;
```

Does that make any sense?

EDIT:
Since your `$topicModel->grades` is an array. Let's foreach it

```php
foreach($topicModel->grades as $grade) {
    $gradeColumnName = "tlm_{$grade}";
    $topicLookupMasterModel->$gradeColumnName = $grade;
}
```

Comment: what is your php version?
mine is php7.4 and work just fine
https://i.imgur.com/U00N6s4.png

Comment: in my case $topicModel->grades  are storing as multiple values in db like this [
    "8",
    "12"
]

Comment: I think the solution is the same, just foreach and you will achive it. https://i.imgur.com/WThXfAj.png

Comment: i am getting same error only can u please modifiy in u r answer

Comment: this is  how i am getting in dd from $topicModel->grades array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "5"
]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller :

```
$arrayTostring = implode(',', $request->input('grades'));
$topicLookupMasterModel{'tlm'.$topicModel->grades} = $topicModel['grades'];
```

[image]

Comment: where did you use your $arrayToString variable..can u please modifiy u r answer brifely

Comment: On my controller

Comment: I use it on my store function

Comment: Don't forget to post the correct code too.

Comment: for single grade its working if i have multiple grades getting error as Unknown column 'tlm_1,5'

Comment: Hmmm, have you try to revome the 'tlm' ?

Comment: $arrayTostring = implode(',', $request->input('grades'));
        $gradeColumnName = "tlm_{$arrayTostring}";
        $topicLookupMasterModel->$gradeColumnName = $arrayTostring; this is my code

Comment: if i have multiple grades getting error as Unknown column 'tlm_1,5'

Comment: So you combine it with another code from another answer right ?, Have you try to just write my code ?

Comment: yes..i didnt get your answer how i can implement it..can u please post it correctly

Comment: Owkayy, I'll post the image for it

Comment: used the same code same error Unknown column 'tlm1,5'

Comment: Sorry bro if i can't help, i'll vote your question